# Simple Rigging/Armature - not separating

Tags: rigging

I'm quite new to Blender

I'm trying to make a very simple rigged item - a box with a "lid." I'd like the box lid to open and close.

However, whenever I rig it all, the lid seems to get stuck to the other side. I've split and separated each lid into its own object.. so I'm not sure what's going on.

Can anyone help explain this to me? It's like the center of the two box lids is sealed together.

[image: Closed box lid]

[image: Open box lid]

here's a link to the blend file:
[Box Blend File](https://pasteall.org/blend/fa30db0037864aa0a7ee0aeac8cffa35)

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: how did you parent the box to the armature? as Chris says, please share the file, it will help to understand your problem: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Added the blend file

Comment: The way you've done it in the blend file you provided works just fine, but it is possible to do it much more simply with a single object and armature.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. Yes I get the same result in Object mode... but when I go to Pose mode, that's when I get the twisting. Should it work properly in pose mode too?

Comment: of course. but it is best to press R X so it rotates "clean" or you lock y and z axis for rotation

Comment: If you want to understand _why_ your rig wasn't working, take a look at my answer, which explains it.  Note that the way in Chris' answer works for very simple situations like yours, but bone parenting rather than using vertex groups is very limited and you should learn how to use vertex groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the apparent twisting is that you haven't properly parented the armatures to the two lids.  I'll discuss `Armature` and `Cube.001`, but the same thing applies to either.

If you select `Cube.001` in object mode and then go into weight paint mode you'll see something like this:

[image: Cube.001 in weight paint mode]

This is telling you that if you zero weight on the inside seam of the cube, meaning that `Bone` will not move that part of the cube.  You can (and should) learn about [weight painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/introduction.html), but for this simple example, here's a different technique:

1. Take the cube to edit mode.
2. Select all vertices.
3. Select `Bone` in Properties -> Object Data Properties.
4. Make sure Weight is set to 1.
5. Hit assign.

Now when you take `Armature` into pose mode and rotate it on X, it will work fine.

You can do the same thing for `Armature.002` and `Cube.002` and your box lid will work the way you intended.

Then you can work out how to merge the two armatures and have a simple lid with a simple armature.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I had done the Properties > Bone > assign thing but I hadn't selected all vertices. I believe I had only selected the face.

Comment: @Brant I suspect you had selected an edge rather than the face, probably the one you used to position the 3D cursor before you added (or moved) the bone into place.  A face would have gotten you all four vertices, usually.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

parent it like this:

select your plane

Shift-select your bone

Press CTRL-P and choose bone

[image]

i would recommend to lock the axis like this:

[image]

repaired file:

[image]

---

---

---

i would do it this way:

create a default cube, half size y, and move it like this (z = 0):

[image]

add an armature:

[image]

select the cube, shift-select the armature:

[image]

CTRL - P -> Bone

[image]

now select cube and armature in object mode:

[image]

Shift - D (press Return)

select both armatures: CTRL - J

now select armature

switch to Pose mode

R Z 180

[image]

check: in front

[image]

[image]

you can now select a bone and e.g. press R X

[image]

one step further, if you want to move both together:

Add an empty:

[image]

add this bone constraint to the left bone:

[image]

add this bone constraint to the right bone:

[image]

then by just moving the empty you will get:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Chris' solution would be to merge the box objects in one object and also merge the armatures in one armature (change the bone names to *right* and *left*, also create a third bone, *root* bone, that will be the parent of *right* and *left*), then parent the box to the armature *With Empty Groups*, which will create empty vertex groups in the objects, that will have the same name as the bones of the armature:

[image]

Then switch the box to *Edit* mode, select the left lid and assign it to the group called *left* so that it is controlled by the left bone (also assign the right lid to the vertex group called *right* and the rest of the mesh to the *root* vertex group):

[image]

Comment: If you do this, and it is a good approach, it would also be useful to add a `root` bone, parent the two lid bones to it, and assign all of the non-lid vertices to the `root` bone, so that you can keep the box structure intact while moving the whole box.

Comment: sure, I didn't want to go into much details

Comment: The main reason I was using separate objects for each piece was because I am importing the whole thing into Roblox and that seemed to be how to have them come over as separate pieces over there (Which is what I wanted).  Thank you for the alternative though -- I have a lot to learn with blender.